# How can I use ::theme pseudo-element?

Tags: css, pseudo-element, shadow-dom

I've found an article about this pseudo-element [here](http://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-shadow-parts/#part-theme). So, I tried use it in my project, but it doesn't work.

Maybe it has an experimental version? If so, how can I use it?

Thanks

Comment: Could you include your code?

Comment: that articls is obselete as you can read, check this one instead:

Comment: Thanks for help. I've found solutiuon. In my case, I need to use the [PolymerLabs/part-theme](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/part-theme) module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution!
In my case, I need to use the [PolymerLabs/part-theme](https://github.com/PolymerLabs/part-theme) module.

Thank you all for your help.